# Python: Reference existing webdriver object's session

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have my test class calling utilities for my tests. These have REST. CLI and UI utils. For the UI, i need a webdriver object

So each utility has its own class

My config is set to use UI in this case

1. Test calls Utility_A method
2. Test calls Utility_B method

So ill create my webdriver object inside the UI utility A. How does Utility B reference the same object

Note that the REST and CLI configs dont use webdrivers so i cant just create the driver session and pass it down in the test class

Comment: Why do you need to have UI and CLI tests in the same test class?

Comment: It means that the test steps are the same regardless. So that a manual can simply list the steps without needing to know the inner workings of the UI, REST or CLI